# git checkout a branch, checkout back to first branch, now everything deleted in red

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I have a peculiar problem. I've been doing work on a branch on a project. I committed after my work and then I wanted to switch to another branch so I typed in `git checkout <branchname>`. When I immediately switched back to my initial branch using `git checkout <firstbranchname>` I ran `git status` and it gave me all of these in red:

```
deleted:    .gitmodules
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Bolts
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFAppLink.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFAppLinkNavigation.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFAppLinkResolving.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFAppLinkTarget.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFCancellationToken.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFCancellationTokenRegistration.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFCancellationTokenSource.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFDefines.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFExecutor.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFMeasurementEvent.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFTask.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFTaskCompletionSource.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFURL.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/Bolts.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Headers/BoltsVersion.h
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Info.plist
deleted:    Bolts.framework/Modules/module.modulemap
modified:   DTIActivityIndicatorView-Swift (modified content)
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFACL.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFAnalytics.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFAnonymousUtils.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFCloud.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFConfig.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFConstants.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFFile.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFGeoPoint.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFInstallation.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFNullability.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject+Subclass.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFProduct.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFPurchase.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFPush.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFQuery.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFRelation.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFRole.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFSession.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFSubclassing.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFUser.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/PFUserAuthenticationDelegate.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Headers/Parse.h
deleted:    Parse.framework/Info.plist
deleted:    Parse.framework/Modules/module.modulemap
deleted:    Parse.framework/Parse
deleted:    Parse.framework/en.lproj/Parse.strings
deleted:    Parse.framework/third_party_licenses.txt
deleted:    ParseCrashReporting.framework/Headers/ParseCrashReporting.h
deleted:    ParseCrashReporting.framework/Info.plist
deleted:    ParseCrashReporting.framework/Modules/module.modulemap
deleted:    ParseCrashReporting.framework/ParseCrashReporting
deleted:    ParseCrashReporting.framework/third_party_licenses.txt
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Info.plist
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Localizable.strings
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtils.framework/ParseFacebookUtils
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtils.framework/third_party_licenses.txt
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework/Headers/ParseFacebookUtilsV4.h
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework/Info.plist
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework/Localizable.strings
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework/Modules/module.modulemap
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework/ParseFacebookUtilsV4
deleted:    ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework/third_party_licenses.txt
deleted:    ParseTwitterUtils.framework/Headers/PFTwitterUtils.h
deleted:    ParseTwitterUtils.framework/Headers/PF_Twitter.h
deleted:    ParseTwitterUtils.framework/Headers/ParseTwitterUtils.h
deleted:    ParseTwitterUtils.framework/Info.plist
deleted:    ParseTwitterUtils.framework/Localizable.strings
deleted:    ParseTwitterUtils.framework/Modules/module.modulemap
deleted:    ParseTwitterUtils.framework/ParseTwitterUtils
deleted:    ParseTwitterUtils.framework/third_party_licenses.txt
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFCollectionViewCell.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFImageView.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFLogInView.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFLogInViewController.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFProductTableViewController.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFPurchaseTableViewCell.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFQueryCollectionViewController.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFQueryTableViewController.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFSignUpView.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFSignUpViewController.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFTableViewCell.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/PFTextField.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/ParseUI.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Headers/ParseUIConstants.h
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Info.plist
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/Modules/module.modulemap
deleted:    ParseUI.framework/ParseUI
modified:   Podfile
modified:   Podfile.lock
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/LICENSE
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/AbstractActionSheetPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/AbstractActionSheetPicker.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetCustomPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetCustomPicker.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetCustomPickerDelegate.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetDatePicker.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetDatePicker.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetDistancePicker.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetDistancePicker.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetLocalePicker.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetLocalePicker.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetStringPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/ActionSheetStringPicker.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/DistancePickerView.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/DistancePickerView.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/SWActionSheet.h
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/Pickers/SWActionSheet.m
deleted:    Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/README.md
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/AbstractActionSheetPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/ActionSheetCustomPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/ActionSheetCustomPickerDelegate.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/ActionSheetDatePicker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/ActionSheetDistancePicker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/ActionSheetLocalePicker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/ActionSheetPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/ActionSheetStringPicker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/DistancePickerView.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/SWActionSheet.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQLocationMediaItem.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMediaItem.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessageData.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessageMediaData.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesAvatarImage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesBubbleImage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesBubbleSizeCalculating.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesBubblesSizeCalculator.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCellTextView.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionView.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionViewDataSource.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesCollectionViewLayoutAttributes.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesComposerTextView.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesInputToolbar.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesKeyboardController.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesLabel.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesLoadEarlierHeaderView.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesMediaPlaceholderView.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesToolbarButtonFactory.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesToolbarContentView.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQPhotoMediaItem.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQSystemSoundPlayer+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQVideoMediaItem.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/NSBundle+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/NSString+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/UIColor+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/UIDevice+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/UIImage+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/UIView+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerChangeRequestMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerChangeResponseMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerClearRequestMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerClearResponseMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerConnection.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerDeviceInfoRequestMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerDeviceInfoResponseMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerDisconnectMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerSnapshotRequestMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerSnapshotResponseMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerTweakRequestMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPABTestDesignerTweakResponseMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPAbstractABTestDesignerMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPApplicationStateSerializer.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPCategoryHelpers.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPClassDescription.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPDesignerEventBindingMessage.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPDesignerSessionCollection.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPEnumDescription.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPEventBinding.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPLogger.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPNotification.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPNotificationViewController.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPObjectIdentifierProvider.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPObjectIdentityProvider.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPObjectSelector.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPObjectSerializer.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPObjectSerializerConfig.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPObjectSerializerContext.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPPropertyDescription.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPSequenceGenerator.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPSurvey.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPSurveyNavigationController.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPSurveyQuestion.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPSurveyQuestionViewController.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPSwizzler.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPTweak.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPTweakInline.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPTweakInlineInternal.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPTweakStore.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPTypeDescription.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPUIControlBinding.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPUITableViewBinding.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPValueTransformers.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPVariant.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/MPWebSocket.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/NSData+MPBase64.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/NSInvocation+MPHelpers.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/UIColor+MPColor.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/UIImage+MPAverageColor.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/UIImage+MPImageEffects.h
deleted:    Pods/Headers/Private/Mixpanel/_MPTweakBindObserver.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Base.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_min.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_min@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_min@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_min_tailless.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_min_tailless@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_min_tailless@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_regular.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_regular@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_regular@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_stroked.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_stroked@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_stroked@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_stroked_tailless.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_stroked_tailless@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_stroked_tailless@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_tailless.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_tailless@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/bubble_tailless@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/clip.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/clip@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/clip@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/play.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/play@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/play@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/typing.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/typing@2x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Images/typing@3x.png
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Sounds/message_received.aiff
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/Sounds/message_sent.aiff
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/ar.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/de.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/en.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/es.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/fr.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/he.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/it.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/ja.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/ko.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/nl.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/pl.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/pt.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/ro.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/ru.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/tr.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/zh-Hans.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Assets/JSQMessagesAssets.bundle/zh-Hant.lproj/JSQMessages.strings
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/JSQSystemSoundPlayer+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/JSQSystemSoundPlayer+JSQMessages.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/NSBundle+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/NSBundle+JSQMessages.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/NSString+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/NSString+JSQMessages.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/UIColor+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/UIColor+JSQMessages.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/UIDevice+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/UIDevice+JSQMessages.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/UIImage+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/UIImage+JSQMessages.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/UIView+JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Categories/UIView+JSQMessages.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesKeyboardController.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesKeyboardController.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.xib
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesToolbarButtonFactory.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesToolbarButtonFactory.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Layout/JSQMessagesBubbleSizeCalculating.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Layout/JSQMessagesBubblesSizeCalculator.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Layout/JSQMessagesBubblesSizeCalculator.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Layout/JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.h
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Layout/JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.m
deleted:    Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Layout/JSQMessages
```

...etc

Essentially saying that my entire project was deleted. WTF happened? All I did was checkout a branch and then checkout back to the first branch. I didn't even modify anything in the second branch before I switched back. When I open the project, all of the files I made are still there but all of the frameworks are now missing. What do I do to restore this? Again, all I did was checkout a branch. I'm venting right now because I get so gun shy with using git because I'm not that well experienced and then I do something small and the whole project comes crashing down. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** As a side note, when I run `git log` and checkout my latest commit that I just committed with all my work using `git checkout <commit>` it still says everything and frameworks are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "git status" says "deleted:" about a file,
it means that this file is present in the git history
(in the current local branch).
So, to get your files back from git history to the
file system use the below command:

`git ls-files --deleted | xargs git checkout`

Comment: I just tried this on a sample project to mimic the same deletion and it didn't do anything. See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ChZinJk.png

Comment: So, you say it worked, right? I see the the deleted file was restored from the git history.

Comment: That part says it worked but when I reopen the project the file is still nowhere to be found. Any ideas?

Comment: This ended up working but I needed to perform a `git reset HEAD .` afterwards to bring my branch back to its initial form. Thanks for the help

Comment: Probably `git checkout thebranch && git reset --hard HEAD` is what you needed. But I answered your exact question - how to restore the **deleted** files. The `git reset --hard ...` command does more than that.